# TFS 2018 will not let me rename a folder

Tags: tfs, tfvc

After playing around a bit - I was able to rename the sub-folders in my projects in Team Foundation Server but it will not let me rename the root project folder.  Any ideas why?  Below is a screen shot to illustrate the problem.

[image]

As you can see I was able to rename the folder under UniversalCheckInApp to UniversalCheckInKiosk but I cannot rename its parent folder as the rename option is disabled when I right click on that folder.  Some more information - Dev folder that is the parent of UniversalCheckInApp is not mapped but the UniversalCheckInApp folder is mapped to a local folder.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so after playing some more - I was able to figure it out.  I had to do a mapping at the Dev folder level. Then the rename option became available for the UniversalCheckInApp folder.  It would be really nice if Microsoft would work on a better way of doing this.

Comment: Microsoft is not investing in TFVC anymore, as centralized version control is largely being supplanted throughout the industry by distributed VC, specifically Git.